# Axios get request with parameters to filter find certrain createdAt range in mongodb

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, axios

I've in my react frontend multiple dates in an Array with this format 'MM/YYYY'
Now I want to get my history from MongoDB that's createdAt the time range of one month.
How can i pass my data in this axios get request?

My Frontend

```
let date = '11/2022'

    const getHistory = async () => {

      let monthYearStart = dayjs(date, 'MM/YYYY').format('YYYY.MM.01');
      let monthYearEnd = dayjs(date, 'MM/YYYY').format('YYYY.MM.32');

      const res = await axios.get('/api/monthlyhistory');
      setPdfHistory(res.data);
    };
    getHistory().then(() => {});
```

My Backend

```
try {
      const history = await History.find({
        status: true,
        createdAt: {
          $gte: dayjs(new Date(monthYearStart, 'YYYY.MM.DD')),
          $lt: dayjs(new Date(monthYearEnd, 'YYYY.MM.DD')),
        },
      });
      res.json(history);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to pass the dates as [query parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query). I would recommend using ISO 8601 format to remove ambiguity use the native `Date` constructor

Client-side

```js
// Note these are local dates
const monthYearStart = new Date(2022, 10); // month is a zero-based index
const monthYearEnd = new Date(monthYearStart);
monthYearEnd.setMonth(monthYearEnd.getMonth() + 1);
monthYearEnd.setDate(monthYearEnd.getDate() - 1);

const res = await axios.get("/api/monthlyhistory", {
  params: {
    monthYearStart: monthYearStart.toISOString(),
    monthYearEnd: monthYearEnd.toISOString(),
  },
});
```

Server-side

```js
const { monthYearStart, monthYearEnd } = req.query;
const history = await History.find({
  status: true,
  createdAt: {
    $gte: new Date(monthYearStart),
    $lt: new Date(monthYearEnd),
  },
});
```